# Invert larger numbers to (close to) zero and zeros to larger numbers

Tags: c#, math

[image: Text]

I would like to transform the number beings used to create this slope/sine in the sample below to "inverse" numbers that I am showing in the goal image below.

So;
A value that is close to 1 would transform to something close to 0.
A value that is close to -1 would transform to something close to 0.
A positive value that is close to 0 would transform to something close to 1.
A negative value that is close to 0 would transform to something close to -1.

Unfortunately I don't know how to better phrase the question. I don't think I actually want "inverse" numbers, so hopefully my request makes sense. I am trying to understand what Math logic I can use to achieve my goal.

Thank you.

Comment: "A negative value that is close to 0 would transform to something close to -1." looks like your input values are positive, no?

Comment: not in the illustration, but the logic would need to work in the same way with negative numbers

Comment: Do you want to modify your actual data?...or simply display your data differently?  The latter would be easier; just flip the y-axis and offset?  A better idea of how your data is represented and how you plan to use it might be helpful.

Comment: If that first one is say `y = x^2` then I'd say the "inverse" you want would be `y = 1 - x^2`  so basically negate the value and add approximately one.

Comment: It looks like you want g(x) = 1 - f(x)

Comment: Your illustration seems to display the time domain on the x-axis.Drawing a diagram in a different way should make things clearer. Input = x-axis, desired output = y-axis. It ressembles [Dawson Integral](http://www.ebyte.it/library/codesnippets/DawsonIntegralApproximations.html).

Comment: @PhilipSmith The requirements you state in the text and your illustrations contradict each other. You state "*A positive value that is close to 0 would transform to something close to 1.A negative value that is close to 0 would transform to something close to -1.*" That would mean the function is undefined at 0 (because it should have a different value depending from which side you approach) and jump from -1 to 1 when x changes the sign from positive to negative. Neither can be seen in the illustration.

Comment: @PhilipSmith Furthermore, you are talking about "large numbers", yet you only define the behaviour for -1 < x < 0 and 0 < x < 1. What should the result be, when x is for insance 100000 or -100000?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
public static double Transform(double x) {
   if (Math.Abs(x) > 1) Throw new ArgumentException("Absolute value must be less or equals than 1");
   return Math.Sign(x) - x;
}
```